# Making an Application for the Linux command line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, console

I've been trying to make a package for the Linux command line. I have a few questions that will probably seem silly to those of you seasoned developers out there, but the documentation and guides online have been unclear to say the least.

I'm actually a developer myself and have been for the past several years but have never dipped my toe into making applications/packages for the Linux terminal, but I now have to do it for work. I would prefer to do it in C# or Python if possible, but the only thing that I've been able to get working is Bash scripts. There's no initialization or template I could find online for making one of these Linux Terminal packages. I might be bad at googling, but after three hours, I've concluded that there just some sort of secret society that exclusively knows how to make these.

I'm fine with using Bash if I can't make terminal apps/packages in other languages, but it's still a bit annoying. For example, I can't run a file without ".sh" at the end. If I run my app, test.sh, I simply type `test.sh [args]` but if I run another package, such as cat, I can just use `cat filename` without having to type `cat.sh filename`.

In short,

1) Do I have to use Bash?

2) If so, how can I run scripts without the ".sh" extension?

3) If not, how can I make terminal apps with C#, Python, etc.? Is there some kind of template to get you started?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `mv test.sh myapp` then you can `myapp [args]`. for *terminal apps* i'm not quite sure what you mean but a simple python script can also be run from terminal.

Comment: @lcy: What problem do you have with Python? Provided Python is installed and in your PATH, you can run your Python program by `python3 YOURPROGRAM`.

Comment: It is better to write your scripts without `.sh`, that way you can change the implementation to another language without changing the interface. However, don't `mv test.sh test`, because `test` is an internal command. `./test` will still work, but you will get rather confused after typing `test`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I learned from this thread and Walter was able to answer my specific question. I should have been more clear in my initial response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Do I have to use Bash (to make applications/packages for the Linux terminal)?

No, you can program in any programming language installed in your machine.

> 2) If so, how can I run scripts without the ".sh" extension?

The `.sh` extension is a convention for Bash scripts, not a requirement. You can use any extension. Suppose `my_script`, `my_script.sh` and `my_script.bash` have the same contents, then these commands are equivalent:

```sh
$ bash my_script.sh
$ bash my_script.bash
$ bash my_script
```

You could also make the script executable with `chmod +x my_script.sh` and run it as `./my_script.sh`

> 3) If not, how can I make terminal apps with C#, Python, etc.? Is there some kind of template to get you started?

To run programs in a given language, you have to install the language first. Installation is typically done with a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager#Comparison_of_commands). Alternatively you could download the language source code and build it. Then you can create programs with that language. This is a sample Python script and its output:

```sh
$ cat my_script.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "test"

$ ./my_script.py
test
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.